# Only admin should run wordpress plugin shortcode

Tags: plugin-development

I have created a simple plugin that locks down content for users not logged in and it is working fine. However any user on a multi-author site could use the same short code in his post to lock down content too. I do not want this to happen.

How may I restrict this functionality to administrators only?
This current code thows up a fatal error:Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

```
public function check_user_role() {
  if(current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' )) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I then intended to use this method in my class constructor to determine if the add_shortcode() function should run. Any clues how I should go about implementing this shall be appreciated.

Comment: this is not how shortcodes are supposed to be used, therefor it is very unlikely that you will be able to actually do it without leaving some potentioal holes. The only setting in which it might work is when every change needs an admin approval

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

This can be fixed by declaring `check_user_role` only when WP is ready, hooking into `wp` (to use WordPress functions and methods) or performing other workaround.

Simply check if `manage_options` capability is there for the user too ( or verify if administrator is in the roles list `in_array( "administrator", $current_user->roles )` ):

```
add_action("wp", function() { 
    function check_user_role() {
        return current_user_can( "manage_options" ) && current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' );
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how do I implement your concept? see my code below `
    function __construct()
    {
        add_shortcode('member', array( $this, 'check_login' ));
    }
    public function check_login($atts, $content = null)
    {         
        if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_null($content) && !is_feed())
        {             
            return do_shortcode($content);         
        }
        else
        {
            return '<p>You must be <a href="'.wp_login_url(get_permalink()).'">logged in</a> to view this post..</p>';     
        }
    }`

Comment: It depends on how you call `check_user_role()`. Do you call it when `wp` is ready? oh, simply add `public function check_user_role() { ...` to the class and then check as `$class->check_user_role()`..

Answer (score -2):

To restrict the use of the shortcode on posts created by administrators only, I need to check if the post author of the post viewed is an administrator as shown in code `if ( user_can( $post->post_author, 'activate_plugins' ) )`. IF not, the content is returned without executing the `do_shortcode($content)` function.

The `current_user_can()` function is not appropriate as it checks the current user and not the post author.

```
public function check_login($atts, $content = null)
{         
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_null($content) && !is_feed())
    {             
        return do_shortcode($content);         
    }
    else
    {
        global $post;           
        if ($post instanceof \WP_Post) {
            if ( user_can( $post->post_author, 'activate_plugins' ) ) {
                return '<p>You must be logged in to view this post..</p>';   
            }
            return $content; 
        }           
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: anyone that can edit the post will be able to change or remove the shortcode, so not a real restriction here